# Regex exclude matches where last two characters of string are combination of - and number

Tags: regex

Tried with `[^-][^0-9]$`, but this also excludes **d9** or **-a**. I would like this to only work with **-1**, **-2**, **-3** etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an NFA regex with lookbehind support like

```
$(?<!-[0-9])
```

It matches an end of string that is not immediately preceded with a `-` + a digit.

A variation of this is

```
^(?!.*-[0-9]$)
^(?!.*-[0-9]$).*
```

If you deal with a POSIX (ERE here) regex engine, you can use

```
^(.*([^-].|.[^0-9])|.)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P8V75w/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a group:

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars
  - `([^-].|.[^0-9])` - either a char other than a `-` and then any one char, or any single char and then any char other than a digit
- `|` - or

  - `.` - any one char
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.